# How many combinations of $3$ initials are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Assume everyone has a first name,  middle name, and last name.  How many different $3$ letter initials are possible if none of the initials are the same letter?

Would the answer be $26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24$?

Because for the first initial you have 26 choices. Then for the next initial you have 25 because you used one already. Then for the third initial you have 24 choices because you used two already?

Comment: You would be correct.

Comment: Thank you sir. I tend to overthink these simple problems. Just wanted some assurance.